# How can i solve this "The name attribute is obsolete. Consider putting an id attribute on the nearest container instead."

Tags: w3c-validation

I have find the plugin for one page scroll and where i have to enter the attribute like  to effect the scroll when clicking on the menu BUT the issue is W3C is showing error there.

First way this type of format which is required for the code -

`<a name="aboutus"></a>`

I have tried this way too -

`<a name="http://www.domain.com/newcopy/responsive/index.html#aboutus"></a>`

but not success. Please help.

Also one more error "Element img is missing required attribute src."

```
<img  width="300" height="200" data-original="img/port9.jpg"  alt="Portfolio 4" class="lazy imp-responsive">
```

I have added this code so the lazy load will works.

Comment: "I have tried this way too" - in comparison to *what*? That's the first piece of code that you're showing us.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forget my first code. I have now added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5 (CR):

The [`a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) must *not* have a `name` attribute (however, its use is under some circumstances [obsolete but conforming](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features)). Instead, use the global [`id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

The [`img` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) must have the [`src` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/embedded-content-0.html#attr-img-src).

Comment: I am new in this field, how can i write the ID attribute in here - <a name="aboutus"></a> ? .. Also "SRC" attribute i can't add this too because i have to replace with "data-original" , so the lazy load will works on those images

Comment: @user3152357: You can use `id` on *any* (existing) element, no need to add an `a` element just for this purpose. For example: `<div id="aboutus">…</div>`. Regarding your lazy loading: well, if this script requires you to use invalid HTML, either look for a different script or live with it.

Comment: That's worked. Regarding the lazy load will contact the developer, if not replied than definitely remove the code.